# Methods Available for Derivative Pricing in Mathematica?

Tags: options, monte-carlo, pricing, finite-difference-method

I am using Mathematica to price options (built in functions, no need to reinvent the wheel, right?). In the documentation, the Binomial method is used as an example of specifying a non-standard method. I wanted to try other methods like Finite Difference and MonteCarlo, however, these do not work when I specify them, and I cannot find a list anywhere of the different methods available. Does anyone have any resources that I can use to better understand what is going on under the hood here?

Comment: Hi pyrex, welcome to Quant.SE! I see you have also posted this to [Mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98551) where it fits better in my opinion so I've closed this question. See this question for [guidance on cross-posting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/266114).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because cross-posted to Mathematica.SE